# Ver un Pago en la API de MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago, sandbox

Estuve probando con **Sandbox** el tema de las notificaciones IPN de *MercadoPago*, y todo bien.

El tema es que quiero probar cómo recibir los datos de un pago realizado, y como no se puede probar con **sandbox** (tengo entendido eso, ya que a comprar no figura el pago en el usuario), quise probar con una compra ya realizada de un usuario que ya ha realizado ventas.

Pero al poner el id y token en `https://api.mercadolibre.com/collections/notifications/{id}?access_token={token}`, me retorna esto:

```
Payments Notification
Consulta un pago que fue informado por medio de la IPN
```

Una captura de pantalla:
[image: captura de pantalla]

Así que la pregunta es... si o si tengo que hacer una compra real, hacer que haga la notificación, para finalmente probar como recibir/ver los datos del token?.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Las notificaciones de pago no llegan en sandbox, ya que la url configurada para notificaciones es única para la aplicación, por lo que si la aplicación esta en producción, pruebas en sandbox podrían enviar notificaciones a la misma url que esta escuchando una aplicación productiva generando pagos duplicados o problemas similares.

Una notificación IPN es un Request POST hacia la url especificada con un formato particular, puedes hacer las pruebas simulando una notificación con Postman.

**IPN**: https://www.yoursite.com/notifications_uri?topic=payment&id=123456789

Donde el id, seria el id del pago creado, el resto sigue el flujo normal y `https://www.yoursite.com/notifications_uri` es la url donde ser reciben las notificaciones.

> El endpoint `/collection/notifications/` ha sido deprecado, se debe usar `/v1/payments/`en su lugar, (ver nota de deprecación https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/localization/migrating-v0-v1)